# Filling the area inside of a irregular shaped polygon in opengl es

Tags: opengl-es

I have a set of points that outlines my polygon.  The polygon can have many different shapes including convex shapes (imagine the shape of a crescent moon).  I thought I could fill the inside of these shapes by using a triangle fan that started at the first point on the perimeter, but this fails badly on certain shapes.

How do people get this done?   I wish there was a glPaintBucket function.

Comment: Did you find an easier way to do this than figuring out the polygon triangulation manually?

Comment: No I actually ended up breaking the thing down into triangles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to use the (intrinsically filled) [triangle](http://web.me.com/smaurice/AppleCoder/iPhone_OpenGL/Entries/2009/3/28_OpenGL_ES_01_-_Drawing_Primitives_1_-_Triangles.html) primitive after breaking up your polygon into triangles (start [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) to learn about polygon triangulation).